# How wide can a unit-length planar curve be?

Tags: geometry, optimization, reference-request, curves

The width of a bounded set in the plane is the minimum distance between two parallel lines bounding the set.

Suppose that we have some curve $C: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ of unit length. How large can its width be? Equivalently, if we would like to bend a wire into a shape of unit width, how much wire do we need? (I'll use the latter framing in this post because it makes the numbers a little nicer.)

If one tries forming the wire into a circle or semicircle, $\pi$ units of length are needed. All but one of the sides of a unit square only takes $3$ units. Using $270$ degrees of a circular arc one can do better, with length $\frac{3\pi(2-\sqrt{2})}{2}=2.7604\ldots$.

After playing around with different natural options for a bit, the winner appears to be $\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\approx2.3094$, given by forming the wire into a $60$-degree angle so that its convex hull is the equilateral triangle of width 1.

However, it turns out that this is not optimal! Consider the following construction: Fix $0.5<x<\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Start with the triangle formed by the points $(0,1), (-x,0), (x,0)$. Then, add the circular arcs of radius $1$ from each of the latter two points as they pass through the opposite side of the triangle. Take the convex hull of these three points and two circular arcs, and omit the line segment of length $2x$ at the bottom; the resulting set is our wire.

[image]

Above is a diagram of this construction: the original triangle is marked in blue, the circular arcs (of which only part make it to the convex hull) are marked in red, the straight-line tangents to said arcs are in black, and the portion of the convex hull not on the wire is marked with a dashed line.

It is fairly easy to see that this construction has width $1$, and that the resulting length is

$$2\left(x+\sqrt{4x^2-1}+\arctan(1/x)-\arctan(x)-\arccos(1/2x)\right)$$

As it turns out, this function is minimized around $x=0.521795$, with a wire length of around $2.2783$. (In fact, the derivative of the above function is a rational function, so we can be more precise: $x$ is the unique positive real root of the polynomial $3x^6 + 9x^4 + x^2 - 1$.)

**Is this construction optimal?** I do not believe there are any obvious local improvements one can make, but it's possible that a radically different wire shape could improve on this configuration.

Obviously, there is a lower bound of $1$ on the length of any solution, and by considering the width in two orthogonal directions one can increase this to $\sqrt{2}$. It's tempting to say that the length must be at least $2$, because there must be a point at distance $1$ from the midpoint of the wire, but this only follows if one makes the assumption that the wire lies on the boundary of its convex hull, which I cannot see a good way to justify.

I would be curious to see any improved lower bounds, better solutions than the one given above, or pointers to discussion of this question in the literature.

Comment: Reminds of both the Moser's worm problem and Reuleaux triangle.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: +1.  Yes to Reuleaux triangle, but where we don't need to close the figure.  At first glance, it seems to involve some kind of minimal figure of constant width, but I don't think it is, quite, since closing the figure uses up more wire (shrinking the scale), then is worth the while.

Comment: What about a broken line resembling the teeth of a saw. Taking $m$ "tooth" of side $2m$  each,the curve has lenght $1$.

Comment: @Piquito: I don't understand your construction; can you link to a diagram? If by "broken" you mean "discontinuous", then I am not permitting such constructions, as they can be made arbitrarily short.

Comment: Sorry dear friend.it is difficult for me to write in English what i want to mean.

Comment: A simple lower bound is $\sqrt 5=2.236\dots$ and it is easy to see that it cannot be attained, so your construction is, most likely, optimal. However I cannot prove it at the moment.

Comment: @fedja: Interesting! Could you elaborate on that lower bound? If you wrote it up into an answer, I'd rather award it the bounty than let the 50 reputation go to waste.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect OK, done. I will still think of it a bit more and update my answer if I have any bright ideas :-)

Comment: Interesting problem! As a final outcome I found for the length of wire: $\,\arctan(3/4) + 1/2 \approx 2.2870\,$, which is slightly above your $\,2.2783\,$. I have not been able to improve my outcome, though. Besides this, I'm preoccupied of [detailed explanation](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2021/2021feb20.htm)s :-)

Comment: Oops, must be twice that outcome: $2\arctan(3/4)+1$.

Answer (score 5):

A simple lower bound is $\sqrt 5>2.236$. Just choose the $x$-axis along the line joining the endpoints and $y$-axis perpendicular to it. Then, if your wire is $(x(t),y(t)), t\in I$, we must have $\int_I|y'(t)|dt\ge 2$ (you make a swing of width $1$ in the $y$-coordinate but you have to return to the start) and $\int_I|x'(t)|\ge 1$, so $L=\int_I\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}\ge\sqrt{2^2+1^2}=\sqrt 5$.

Comment: Ah, I see - thanks! A more intuitive way to see this for me is to imagine reflecting portions of the curve along the $x$ and $y$ axes so that one "straightens it out" to point northeast; then it must travel from $(0,0)$ to at least $(1,2)$.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect Yep. That is a fine way too. It looks like it might be possible to prove that your construction is optimal at least among the curves that lie on one side of the line joining the endpoints (though I still need to iron out some details) but the possibility to swing both ways still gives me trouble (though intuitively it is clear that it should be a losing configuration).

Comment: Arent you assuming that the curve is differentiable everywhere? And, as I understand, that is not really a constraint. I have the same question as Han de Bruijn in another "answer"

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso Rectifiable will work for that argument too, but, as you correctly said, it is, indeed, irrelevant. You may think it is a broken line, if you want, just show an inequality for such case and pass to the limit to get the general bound.